# Java: Looping through and printing based on rounding

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, random

I am having trouble figuring out how display a rounded number of asterisks based on their corresponding (numbers on the right of the output) count.

I am attempting to use 1 asterisk to represent 100 asterisks. However, when I get a number such as roll #17 being 417, I want it to print only 4 asterisks, not five; same for rounding up. I tried using Math.round() but I was unsuccessful.

I'd really appreciate any help.

My code:

```
public class Histogram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int numRoles = 30000;
        int[] amountRoles = new int[19]; // amountRoles Holds the Array

        for (int i = 3; i < 7; i++) 
        amountRoles[i] = 0; // Set 0
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numRoles; i++) 
            {
                int die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
                int die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
                int die3 = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
                amountRoles[die1+die2+die3]++; // Increments
            }
            System.out.print("The die was rolled " + numRoles + " times, its six value's counts are:");
            for (int i = 3; i < 7; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(); // Line Holder
            }
        }
        for (int i = 3; i < amountRoles.length; i++) // Iterates through amountRoles
        {
            System.out.print("[" + i + "]" + "  ");
            for(int j = 0; j < amountRoles[i]; j++) // Loop through amountRoles[i]
            {
                if (Math.round(j) % 100 == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print("" + "*");
                }
            }
            System.out.println(" "  + amountRoles[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

My output:

```
[3]     ** 139
[4]     **** 389
[5]     ********* 826
[6]     ************** 1366
[7]     ********************* 2082
[8]     ****************************** 2973
[9]     *********************************** 3440
[10]    *************************************** 3859
[11]    ************************************** 3742
[12]    *********************************** 3482
[13]    ****************************** 2918
[14]    ******************** 1996
[15]    ************** 1341
[16]    ********* 865
[17]    ***** 417
[18]    ** 165
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the part where you print each line:

```
System.out.print("[" + i + "]" + "  ");
for(int j = 0; j < amountRoles[i]; j++) // Loop through amountRoles[i]
{
    if (Math.round(j) % 100 == 0)
    {
        System.out.print("" + "*");
    }
}
System.out.println(" "  + amountRoles[i]);
```

You are looping hundreds of times. That is unnecessary and inefficent. Just use division to get the number of *s to print:

```
System.out.print("[" + i + "]  ");
int starsToPrint = (int) Math.round((double) amountRoles[i] / 100.0);
for (int j = 0; j < starsToPrint; j++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println(" "  + amountRoles[i]);
```

Just for your information, the reason your original code was broken was because 0 % 100 == 0, so on the first iteration of your inner for loop it would print an extra "*".

Comment: What you have there doesn't deal with rounding upwards though, only rounding down. So 773 would print 7 asterisks when 8 is the hope. Example being since 773 > 750, round up and print 8 asterisks, 742 < 750, round down and print 7 asterisks.

Comment: @Aramza ah I see. No problem, that's really easy to fix. Let me edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just divide amountRoles[i] by 100 and round that.
Of course, this wouldn't print any asterisk for amountRoles[i] <= 50 but I'm guessing that's what you want.

```
    for(int j = 0; j < Math.round(amountRoles[i] / 100); j++) { // Loop through amountRoles[i]
         System.out.print("" + "*");
     }
```